# OpenCV vs SKimage: Is there any operation that can be done with SKimage but not with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, scikit-image

I know both libraries provide several operations to deal with images and accomplish computer vision tasks. My question is:
Is there any operation that can be done with **SKimage** but not with **OpenCV**?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes there are. Please refer to the documentation on each for a list of methods that are available.

Comment: One such operation is finding multiple threshold values for a single grayscale image. Imagine an image with only 3 different intensity values (a, b, c). `OpenCV` provides functions to threshold only a single value. But `skimage` provides [multi threshold function](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_multiotsu.html) which you can use to segment intensities of value a, b or c